# how to group by with multiple querys on pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, count, filtering

I got stuck with multiple querys on a single table result, like this

Result expected:

| SEMESTRE | Number of 'CACHIMBOS' | Number of 'REGULAR' | Number of 'EGRESANTE' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-I | counts | X | X |
| ... |  |  |  |
| 2021-II | 41 | 453 | 40 |

I am doing filtering by 2 last columns

```
df9 = df.iloc[:, [11,12]]
df9
```

Result (df9)

```
    Condicion   Semestre
0   REGULAR 2019-I
1   REGULAR 2019-I
2   REGULAR 2019-I
5   EGRESANTE   2019-I
8   REGULAR 2019-I
... ... ...
3008    REGULAR 2021-II
3009    REGULAR 2021-II
3010    REGULAR 2021-II
3011    REGULAR 2021-II
3012    REGULAR 2021-II
```

Codes that i am trying to get querys...

```
options = ['CACHIMBO', 'REGULAR', 'EGRESANTE']
new_df = df9[df9['Condicion'].isin(options)]
new_df
```

```
raa = new_df.groupby(['Condicion', df9.iloc[:,1] == '2021-II'] ).size().reset_index(name='Total')
raa
```

```
raa1 = raa.loc[raa['Semestre'] == True]
raa1
```

so I think this is the closest to query that I spected

```
tabla1 = raa1.loc[:, raa1.columns != 'Semestre']
tabla1
```

```
Condicion   Total
0   CACHIMBO    41
2   EGRESANTE   40
4   REGULAR 453
```

Is there any way to simplify this?
Merge DataFrame results is it correct?

Result expected:

| SEMESTRE | Number of 'CACHIMBOS' | Number of 'REGULAR' | Number of 'EGRESANTE' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-I | 0 | X | X |
| 2019-II | X | x | x |
| 2020-I |  |  |  |
| 2020-II |  |  |  |
| 2021-I |  |  |  |
| 2021-II | 41 | 453 | 40 |

Answer (score 0):

def DDD_per_patient_per_month(group):
group["DDD_per_patient per month"] = group["Patients Registered"] / group["DDD"]
return group

df.groupby(["Practice", "Month", "BNF"]).apply(DDD_per_patient_per_month)